# pull request attachment using rest api is not visible inside comments section of overview tab AzureDevops

Tags: rest, azure-devops, pull-request

I want to upload code analysis results in a pull request so I posted a file using Azuredevops rest api,
fortunately, comment and attachment is being posted but the attachment is not visible inside the comment section of an overview tab.
I use the `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0` document to generate my request.
looking for help.